# C# OpenXML search a particular word or sentence and apply Content control to it

Tags: c#, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I am trying to search the text in the OpenXML document and once the searched text is found, I want to apply the content control on it. I have followed the below code and able to search the text but I am stuck at the place where I need to apply the content control.

For now I am searching the text in the document inside all the paragraphs which contains hello, and it is able to search it. On applying content control on the searched text, I am getting an error :-

> sdtContentBlock.Append(p.Text);

As `sdtContentBlock.Append()` accepts the argument  of type `OpenXMLElement` and `p.Tex`t is a `string`. Any suggestion how can I append the text node inside the content control? Also, is there any way to search the text using offset values so that a word in specific range gets searched not all of it's occurrences.

```
foreach (var p in helloParagraphs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("StyleName:{0}{1}", p.Text, p.ParagraphNode);
    SdtBlock sdtBlock = new SdtBlock();
    SdtProperties sdtProperties = new SdtProperties();
    Tag tag = new Tag() { Val = "cc1" };
    sdtProperties.Append(tag);
    SdtContentBlock sdtContentBlock = new SdtContentBlock();
    // Here, I want to wrap the searched textNode inside Content Control. For e.g, <w:t>Hello</w:t>
    sdtContentBlock.Append(p.Text);
    sdtBlock.Append(sdtProperties);
    sdtBlock.Append(sdtContentBlock);
 }
```

Below is the whole code  and OpenXML document for reference-

```
public static void ApplyContentControl()
{
    const string fileName = "D:\\POC\\ContentControlApp\\ContentControlApp\\Doc1.docx";
    const string documentRelationshipType =
          "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
    const string stylesRelationshipType =
          "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles";
    const string wordmlNamespace =
          "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

    XNamespace w = wordmlNamespace;
    XDocument xDoc = null;
    XDocument styleDoc = null;

    using (Package wdPackage = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        PackageRelationship docPackageRelationship =
              wdPackage.GetRelationshipsByType(documentRelationshipType).FirstOrDefault();
        if (docPackageRelationship != null)
        {
            Uri documentUri = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative),
                  docPackageRelationship.TargetUri);
            PackagePart documentPart = wdPackage.GetPart(documentUri);
            //Load the document XML in the part into an XDocument instance.
            xDoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(documentPart.GetStream()));
            //Find the styles part. There will only be one.
            PackageRelationship styleRelation =
                  documentPart.GetRelationshipsByType(stylesRelationshipType).FirstOrDefault();
            if (styleRelation != null)
            {
                Uri styleUri =
                 PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(documentUri, styleRelation.TargetUri);
                 PackagePart stylePart = wdPackage.GetPart(styleUri);
                 //Load the style XML in the part into an XDocument instance.
                styleDoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(stylePart.GetStream()));
            }
        }
     }

     string defaultStyle = (string)(from style in styleDoc.Root.Elements(w + "style")
                         where (string)style.Attribute(w + "type") == "paragraph" &&
                         (string)style.Attribute(w + "default") == "1"
                         select style).First().Attribute(w + "styleId");

     // Find all paragraphs in the document.
     var paragraphs = from para in xDoc .Root.Element(w + "body").Descendants(w + "p")
            let styleNode = para
                            .Elements(w + "pPr")
                            .Elements(w + "pStyle")
                            .FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
                ParagraphNode = para,
                StyleName = styleNode != null ?
                    (string)styleNode.Attribute(w + "val") :
                    defaultStyle
            };

        // Retrieve the text of each paragraph.
        var paraWithText =
            from para in paragraphs
            select new
            {
                ParagraphNode = para.ParagraphNode,
                StyleName = para.StyleName,
                Text = ParagraphText(para.ParagraphNode)
            };

        // Following is the new query that retrieves all paragraphs
        // that have specific text in them.
        var helloParagraphs =
            from para in paraWithText
            where para.Text.Contains("Hello")
            select new
            {
                ParagraphNode = para.ParagraphNode,
                StyleName = para.StyleName,
                Text = para.Text
            };

        foreach (var p in helloParagraphs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StyleName:{0}{1}", p.Text, p.ParagraphNode);

            SdtBlock sdtBlock = new SdtBlock();
            SdtProperties sdtProperties = new SdtProperties();
            Tag tag = new Tag() { Val = "cc1" };
            sdtProperties.Append(tag);
            SdtContentBlock sdtContentBlock = new SdtContentBlock();
            // Here, I want to wrap the searched textNode inside Content Control. For e.g, <w:t>Hello</w:t>
            sdtContentBlock.Append(p.Text);
            sdtBlock.Append(sdtProperties);
            sdtBlock.Append(sdtContentBlock);
        }
    }
```

XML File :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document >
    <w:body>
        <w:p w14:paraId="0A445106" w14:textId="562F5252" w:rsidR="00410730" w:rsidRDefault="00E67584">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Hi there!</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w14:paraId="7075F558" w14:textId="4A0D50A9" w:rsidR="00D43DD5" w:rsidRPr="00D43DD5" w:rsidRDefault="00D43DD5">
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Hello!</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00D43DD5" w:rsidRPr="00D43DD5">
            <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="708"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: You may find the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools) to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @user9938 for sharing the link, but I couldn't find anything specific "to applying content control on a word". Can you share how can I find exact I am looking for in this sdk.